# Is there any public react function that gets executed every time state is changed just like render function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component. It should create an object from props and render it. This object should get added as a state.

Below is the current code.

Example:-

```
<popupComponent element={object} />
```

popupComponent.js

```
class popupComponent extends Component {constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        }
    }

    updateName (event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.currentTarget.value
        })
    }


    publishElement () {
        this.props.saveAndClose({
            name: this.state.name
        });

        this.setState({
            name: ""
        })
    }

    render() {

         return (
            <div draggable="true"  >
                    <h4>Name:</h4>
                    <input id="elementName" type="text" placeholder="Enter element name" value={element.name} onChange={this.updateName.bind(this)}/>
                    <button id="saveAndClose" onClick={this.publishElement.bind(this)}>Save & close</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default popupComponent;
```

Question: Which function other than render gets executed whenever state is changed? In this scenario constructor runs only once and I cannot try that because the time constructor gets executed, state isnt available.

Comment: after render function calls componentDidUpdate ,before render function calls componentWillUpdate are the fucntion called whenever there is change in state or props

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate() is also called

Comment: What do you want to do in that function? The question doesn't explain that, and this is what the answer may depend on.

Comment: Resolved issue by conditionally not creating the component at all.

Actual issue, Somehow this component's constructor was getting called only once but I wanted it getting called whenever it gets visually shown.

Resolved issue by conditionally not including the component at all

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by conditionally not creating the component at all.

Actual issue, Somehow this component's constructor was getting called only once but I wanted it getting called whenever it gets visually shown.

Resolved issue by conditionally not including the component at all as below.

```
{this.state.show ? <PopupMarkupEditor   
                    element = {selectedElement}
                    saveAndClose = {this.saveElement}
                    show = {this.state.show}
                    /> : null }
```